# How wp_ajax_nopriv since Wordpress 3.1

Tags: customization, ajax

I have a question.
When I was on Wordpress 3.0, my ajax function worked. It return good things when I'm log in and log out.

add_action('wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action_callback');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action', 'my_action_callback');

Now since Wordpress 3.1, I saw **wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action** *is deprecated*. So, for a visitor, my ajax function doesn't work.

What is the alternative ajax function for Wordpress 3.1 ? Please

Comment: What gives you the idea it is deprecated? I am not aware of such decisions, I do not see that documented and it is still used in code just fine.

Comment: Just implemented an ajax based plugin yesterday on 3.2 and this hooks are still working without any problem.

Comment: @Rarst Check it out http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook/wp_ajax_nopriv_%7B$_post%5Baction%5D%7D

Comment: @Roman your hooks working with _nopriv_ ? Really ?

Comment: @Steffi Jep. Works with/without permissions. I've checked admin-ajax.php and the action `wp_ajax_nopriv_` is still there on line 46.

Comment: @Roman Can you show me how do you that please ?

Comment: @Steffi I havn't done something special here. Just a normal ajax implementation. See in the search for more articles about ajax implementation or ask a new question with your current code.

Answer (score 6):

Site you referred to is likely being updated in automated fashion. The reason it wrongfully claims that action is deprecated is because:

- you are [looking at page](http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook/wp_ajax_nopriv_%7B%24_post%5Baction%5D%7D) for `wp_ajax_nopriv_{$_POST[action]}`
- while in recent WP versions actual code is `wp_ajax_nopriv_{$_REQUEST[action]}` ([also documented on that site](http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook/wp_ajax_nopriv_%7B%24_REQUEST%5Baction%5D%7D)).

So action is not deprecated, its functionality is not changed (only the way variable is accessed) and it is fully functional in current WP version.

Comment: Ah, okay ! Thanks. But why my ajax function works perfectly when I'm log in. But **returns -1** when I'm log out ? I use `wp_ajax_hello` and `wp_ajax_nopriv_hello`

Comment: @Steffi I have no idea. Ask new question about that and include your code?

Comment: Yep, thanks — Here : http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/22305/ajax-function-returns-1