# Ajax function returns -1

Tags: ajax, nonce, logout

I have a question.

I made a simply ajax function.
When I'm logged in, it works perfectly.
When I'm logged out, it returns me -1 (since Wordpress 3.1)

Why ? I don't understand.
Precisely, it returns -1 and my entire HTML code. (lol)
I'm gonna be crazy again.

**PHP (in functions.php)**

```
function say_coucou(){
check_ajax_referer( 'hello', 'nonce' );
echo "Hello";
die(); // this is required to return a proper result
exit;
}
add_action('wp_ajax_hello_hello', 'say_coucou');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_hello_hello', 'say_coucou');
```

**JAVASCRIPT / JQUERY / AJAX (in footer.php) **

```
function blabla(){
    var toSend = {
      action:"hello_hello",
      post_id: "<?php echo $wp_query->post->ID; ?>",
      nonce: "<?php echo js_escape( wp_create_nonce('hello')); ?>"
    };
    url_action = 'http://www.***********/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php';
    $.ajaxSetup({cache:true});
    $.ajax({
      url: url_action,
      type:'POST',
      data: toSend,
      cache: false,
      success:function(results)
      {
        alert(results)
      }
     });
 }
```

Any help, please ? 
Thanks.

Comment: You have typo in nonce creation. With it fixed this works for me both logged in and logged out just fine.

Comment: Oops, I've rewritted it. It's my fault — Now this code doesn't work when I'm logged out =/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Found It!**

I had done a redirect, so my ajax function status was 302...
I deleted the redirect and it worked !

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 2):

Rarst said it worked for him both logged in and logged out, i can also confirm the same, here's my ugly test code that works, very much just a hacked together version of your code(for testing).

```
function say_coucou(){
    check_ajax_referer( 'hello', 'nonce' );
    echo "Hello";
    die;
}
add_action('wp_ajax_hello_hello', 'say_coucou');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_hello_hello', 'say_coucou');
add_action('admin_print_footer_scripts','blabla',20000);
add_action('wp_head','enj',20000);
add_action('wp_footer','blabla',20000);
function enj() {
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
}

function blabla(){
?>
<script type="text/javascript">

    jQuery(document).ready(function($){

        $('a#blabla').click(function(){

            var toSend = {
                action:"hello_hello",
                post_id: "1",
                nonce: "<?php echo esc_js( wp_create_nonce('hello') ); ?>"
            };
            url_action = "<?php echo admin_url('/admin-ajax.php'); ?>";
            $.ajaxSetup({cache:true});
            $.ajax({
                url: url_action,
                type:'POST',
                data: toSend,
                cache: false,
                success:function(results) {
                    alert(results)
                }
            });
        });
    });

</script>
    <a href="#" id="blabla">aaa</a>
    <?php
}
```

Worked both logged out and logged in(obviously not in admin logged out, because there is no admin logged out).

I'd not realistically use the hooks so poorly in real code form, so don't look to my hacky version of your code as a good example of how to do things, because it's not.. (for illustration of working test code only).

Comment: Ah....... But me, I use the "function blabla" in footer.php. whereas you did it in functions.php — Is there a difference ?

Comment: Perhaps you could post up more of your code and additionally detail exactly where your placing it?

Comment: Okay, I updated it. Check it out

Comment: I did exactly the same code, it returns me "-1" (when I'm logged out)

Comment: You added my code from above to your functions file and still got `-1` when logged out? If yes, try with plugins disabled(not sure what else it could be at this point)..